# Why is Half-Life: Source not eligible for Valve coupons?

Tags: steam, half-life-series

According to this [Steam Inventory thingy](http://steamcommunity.com//my/inventory)(the link will show a different inventory for you, obviously), I have a 33% off coupon for Valve titles:

> 33% off any one title on Steam listed with Valve as the publisher.

However, [Half-Life: Source](http://store.steampowered.com/app/280) does not appear in the [List of applicable games](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?list_of_subs=7,25,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,79,219,469,474,515,516,517,518,519,520,558,704,715,716,717,829,1053,1054,1150,1151,2481,2482,2483,2484,2487,2488,2489,2490,4807,7877,7878,7930,7931,7932,7933) for that coupon. Even though the *Game Details* say

> Title: Half-Life: Source
>   Genre: Action
>   Developer: Valve
>   Publisher: Valve
>   Release Date: 1 Jun 2004

So how can I use this coupon to save the incredible amount of 1,65 EUR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All coupons aren't valid until January 2nd. While I understand that HL:Source doesn't show up on the applicable games list, the coupon is valid for it.

Note that **HL:Source** and **HL:Source Death Match** are already 50% off right now, so you might as well purchase it before the sale ends as it is a better deal than the 33% coupon would give you anyways.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that the coupons wont be valid until Jan. 2nd. By then they may have removed the 50% off, good point.